# Writing a double sum in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and am attempting to write a double sum function with two inputs p and q. For instance, to compute my sum on WolframAlpha, I use

```
Sum[p^25 * (1-q)^j * Sum[(25 choose r) * ((j-1) choose (r-1)) * ((q * (1-p)) / (p * (1 - q)))^r,{r,1,25}],{j,0,23}]
```

[Here's an example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum[p%5E25+*+%281-q%29%5Ej+*+Sum[%2825+choose+r%29+*+%28%28j-1%29+choose+%28r-1%29%29+*+%28%28q+*+%281-p%29%29+%2F+%28p+*+%281+-+q%29%29%29%5Er%2C%7Br%2C1%2C25%7D]%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C23%7D]+for+p%3D.6+and+q%3D.5) for `p = .6` and `q = .5`

This should be easy to write in R, but I can't figure out how to do so. (I realize that the choose function becomes `choose(n,k)`, but the sums are proving intractable.)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. +1 for providing the example on WolframAlpha.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

```
p <- 0.6
q <- 0.5
qp <- q*(1-p)/(p*(1-q))
f <- function(r,j) choose(25,r)*choose(j-1,r-1)*qp^r
g <- function(j) p^25*(1-q)^j*sum(sapply(1:25,f,j))
sum(sapply(1:23,g))
# [1] 0.721113
```

You could use anonymous functions instead of `f` and `g` and put it all on one line, but IMO this is a little less confusing.